# What do numbers next to filenames in PyCharm mean?

Tags: pycharm

I'm seeing this in my PyCharm project/files bar:

[image]

I am not sure what that means or what I pressed to get that. A google search does not seem to provide any useful information. Does anyone know what it is and how to remove it?
Also, there are no other numbers in the project (no 4, 3, 2, or 1 files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a PyCharm [bookmark](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/managing-bookmarks.html).